# detect incalculable variables

Tags: linear-algebra, simultaneous-equation

I have a bunch of equations in the form as follows.

```
a+b+c+d=10
c+d+e+f=12
d+e+c=13
```

Where I am tying to calculate the values of each variable (many more equations in the actual list ofc).

However, I cannot separate the values of `a` and `b` (I can only calculate `a+b`) or `d` and `e` (I can only calculate `d+e`). How would I detect these "incalculable" variables (such that I know `a` and `b` must be calculated together and so forth)?

These seems common enough and I know I've seen software do this, but the term for this escapes and and how I would calculate this is well beyond me.

Comment: This is the subject of *linear algebra.* In modern terms, you are asking how to calculate the kernel (or "null space") of a linear transformation.  There are algorithms and they all are versions of solving the system.